# Warning and Fatal Error on Wordpress Homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, directory

I just checked on my website today  at ([www.mediagrooveltd.com](http://mediagrooveltd.com)) and the following error below was thrown. The site has been functional for over a month now with no troubles, what could be the cause of this?

> Warning:
>   require_once(/home/oddity/public_html/mediagrooveltd.com/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/vendor/tribe-common-libraries/tribe-common-libraries.class.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/oddity/public_html/mediagrooveltd.com/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/src/Tribe/Main.php
>   on line 304
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/oddity/public_html/mediagrooveltd.com/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/vendor/tribe-common-libraries/tribe-common-libraries.class.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/oddity/public_html/mediagrooveltd.com/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/src/Tribe/Main.php
>   on line 304

Comment: files were removed, renamed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with the events calendar, some of the files are missing. Or might have been over ridden by an update, for a temporary fix Deactivate the event plugin and see if everything works. If the site does work then you can delete and reinstall the plugin again. Make sure to take a backup of the plugin before deleting it.